# Creating dynamic Prepared Statements to insert into database

Tags: javascript, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to write one row of data into a Google Cloud SQL database, using a prepared statement as described here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc

I have the data stored in an object called valuesByTitle, which looks like this:

{NAME: 'fun event', LOCATION: '123 Main St.'}

The data is inserted into the SQL table if I write everything out like this:

```
var conn = getConnection(); // connects to db
var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO events '
  + '(NAME, LOCATION) values (?, ?)');
stmt.setString(1, valuesByTitle['NAME']);
stmt.setString(2, valuesByTitle['LOCATION']);
stmt.execute();
}
```

However, I would like to automate the process, so I don't have to change the code each time the variables change.

I have two new variables, one for the column names and one for a set of place holders (e.g. "?") for the insert statement.

```
var columns = Object.keys(valuesByTitle);
var placeholders = columns.map(function(column) { 
return "?";
};
```

Using these, this prepared statement should automatically insert whatever is in the valuesByTitle object (assuming all the values are string values):

```
var conn = getConnection();  
var stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO events (" + columns.join(",") + ") VALUES (" + placeholders.join(",") + ")");
for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
stmt.setString(i+1, valuesByTitle[columns[i]]);  
}
stmt.execute();
```

For some reason, it's not inserting the data. Surprised not to find any examples either. Is the logic off or is it just not possible to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your code is OK, you simply forgot to close the `map()` bracket i.e.

```
var columns = Object.keys(valuesByTitle);
  var placeholders = columns.map(function(column) { 
  return "?";
};
```

should be

```
var columns = Object.keys(valuesByTitle);
var placeholders = columns.map(function(column) { 
  return "?";
});
```

(note the ending bracket after `return "?";}`)

Comment: Thanks. That ending bracket was in my code, messed up the copy and paste. I found the problem though. The form the data was coming from had numeric & date values as well, so things stopped when the "setString" line was run. When I leave in just string options in the form, all is well.

Now, I just need to write some conditional rules to handle how the prepared statement is formed based on the type of variable. Like...

    for (i=0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    var type = typeof valuesByTitle[columns[i]]

    if (type === "string") { ...

Comment: If you think this answer is sufficient, please "accept" it on stack overflow. Thanks!